# Updating MySQL table using Python script

Tags: python, mysql

I'm still learning python and I struggle with sql queries

I have a simple table called `diverts`

column 1 is called `chute`
column 2 is called `five`

chute is the primary key and contains `Fa01` to `Fa60`

```
| chute | five |
|-------|------|
| Fa01  | null |
|-------|------|
| Fa02  | null |
|-------|------|
| Fa03  | null |
|-------|------|
```

I have a list of values called `fiveMin` in my script that contains the number of times a specific event relating to that chute happened in a five minute period. I pull this data from elsewhere and populate the list. `fiveMin = [1.0, 23.0, 56.0, .... 39.0, 56.0]` 60 elements in all

I want to update `five` column with that data and every five minutes update with the new data not append it.

I have been successful in updating the five column using the following

```
cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO `ship_diverts` (five) VALUES (%s),(%s),(%s)',
[(item, item, item) for item in fiveMin])
```

but this just adds data to the `five` column, I would like to update each column based on the primary key

```
 | chute | five |
 |-------|------|
 | Fa01  | 1.0  |
 |-------|------|
 | Fa02  | 23.0 |
 |-------|------|
 | Fa03  | 56.0 |
 |-------|------|
```

I am not sure how to achieve this, any suggestions?

I also have `chute_list = ['Fa01', 'Fa02', .... 'Fa60']` which I can pass in to the query for the primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use mysql update statement. it would look like this:

```
UPDATE diverts
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE chute=some_value
```

You could either build an object by first selecting all primary keys, put them in an array and then add whatever values you want where it should go
. But that's the general idea.

There is also a statement called insert on duplicate key update (if column exists it will update, if not it will make new column).

execute many:

```
data = [
( 'Jane', date(2005, 2, 12) , 1),
( 'Joe', date(2006, 5, 23) , 2),
( 'John', date(2010, 10, 3) , 3),
]
stmt = "update employees set first_name = %s, hire_date = %s where id=%s"
cursor.executemany(stmt, data)

 execute:


items = [
( 'Jane', date(2005, 2, 12) , 1),
( 'Joe', date(2006, 5, 23) , 2),
( 'John', date(2010, 10, 3) , 3),
]
stmt = "update employees set first_name = %s, hire_date = %s where id=%s"
for item in items 
    cursor.execute(stmt, item)
```

Comment: based on that i tried `cursor.executemany("'UPDATE ship_divert SET five='%s', WHERE chute='%s'"%[(chute, item) for chute, item in chute_list, fiveMin])` but i get the error `ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Comment: Do your loop outside of the statement and for every item make a new statement with the item as value

Comment: actually just saw the execute many function you can do that as well but still not using the for loop in the statement. You write out whatever the general statement is with %s placeholders for value and then do executemany(statement,items)

Comment: do you mean something like `statement = "'UPDATE diverts SET five='s%' WHERE chute='s%'"(chute,item)`  then `c.executemany(statement,items)` but i'm not sure how to do the loop to pass in the variables

Comment: execute many does the loop for you, you need to loop if just using execute I guess if you need to do some further checks or something like that. I'll put an example for execute in my answer as well.

Comment: yea if you're looping over a few objects or completely updating/inserting some object. Otherwise can just use execute with whatever variables.

Comment: so i have my list `sort_list = ['Fa01', [10.0], 'Fa02', [23.0], 'Fa03', [35.0], 'Fa04', [9.0]]` and i created the query `query = "UPDATE ship_divert SET five = %s, WHERE chute = %s"` and then executemany `cursor.executemany(query,sort_list)` but i get the error `Wrong number of arguments during string formatting`

Comment: Pay attention to the format of data object in my example, each set of values should be within their own index (in parenthesis). Sort_list should be like this sl =[ ('fa01',10)' ('fa02',23), ...]